# Recurret Data structurring

Tags: multivariate-analysis, survival, recurrent-events

I am confused with the structure of recurrent data that can be used with recurrent models. I know that in order to use the recurrent data models(Anderson-Gill (`AG`), `Frailty` , Wei, Lin and Weissfeld (`WLW`), and Prentice, Williams and Peterson models (`PWP`)) we need first to put our dataset in specific format such that we can feed it to the selected model.

**Raw dataset**

I have a medical dataset that describe the annually attendance of patients to do specific test `T`. So for example `patient A` has several records that explain how many times he did the `T` test. In other words, take a look for sample below:

```
ID VisitD Ttest event
A   2000   27    0
A   2001   26    0
A   2003   23    1
A   2006   25    1
```

**Anderson-Gill (`AG`)**

So let us take the `AG` model as an example. I know that in order to use`AG` model we need our data to be in the following format

```
 ID   Start   End   Event
```

to use them in `coxph`, for example, in `survival` package in `R` as

```
 fit <- coxph(Surv(start, end, event)~T+cluster(ID), data=tst)
```

**Question**

So for above sample how do I convert my data to `AG` dataset structure. I am thinking to do the interval by subtracting `1` from each year so for above example `patient A` start his first visit in `1999` to `2000` and from `2000` to `2001` and so on, such that I will end up with the following dataset for the previous dataset example.

```
ID  start   end   Ttest event
A   1999    2000   27    0
A   2000    2001   26    0
A   2002    2003   23    1
A   2005    2006   25    1
```

Do you think I am wrong with my thinking, if so what do you think I have to do to convert my data to specific dataset structure.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you data set should look like this in the end:

```
ID  start   end   Ttest event
A   1999    2000   27    0
A   2000    2001   26    0
A   2001    2003   23    1
A   2003    2006   25    1
```

As you last knew that the test value for patient `A` was 26 between 2001 and 2002. You can though also use your initial `data.frame` but then individual `A` is only at risk between 2000 to 2001 and 2002 to 2003 when you estimate the model with `coxph`. I figure it comes down to whether or not you observe failures for patient `A` between 2001 and 2002.

You can get a `data.frame` as I suggest above using the `tmerge` function in the `survival` package. See `?tmerge` and the vignette referenced in the help page.

Comment: @ Benjamin Christoffersen : thanks for your reply, I will check your suggestion and let you know what I get. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.